# Combine values from multiple rows into a single row

Tags: vba, excel

Sample data in Excel: ('|' represents a cell)

```
    Customer   | Value A | Value B | Year
    Customer 1 | 134     |         | 2009
    Customer 1 |         | 9       | 2009
    Customer 1 | 175     |         |        
    Customer 2 | 515     |         | 2009
    Customer 2 | 1946    | 7       | 2010
    Customer 3 |         |         |
    Customer 3 |         | 154     |
    Customer 3 |         |         | 2011
```

The scenario is that I have a sheet where there are duplicates in a column (say `Customer` here). I need to merge all duplicates for a given 'Customer' into a single row. Meaning, that all rows (of duplicates) will be concatenated into one row. If value for a column is same in both instance of rows, then no concatenation is required.

Following is the expected result:

```
    Customer   | Value A | Value B | Year
    Customer 1 | 134,175 | 9       | 2009
    Customer 2 | 515,1964| 7       | 2009,2010
    Customer 3 |         | 154     | 2011
```

I need VBA to combine duplicate customer details into one row.

Comment: What you have you tried so far? Have you got stuck or are having difficulty with a particular programming puzzle? You will find this community are very glad to help, but we won't complete your task for you.

Comment: How about a pivot table?

Comment: My approach is to get the range of all rows of 'Customer 1" and for "Value A" go through each cell in a column and concatenate values in a csv form. Repeating this process for each column and further repeat this for each customer. I am trying to achieve this through VBA. However I was looking for some clue as to how can this be best achieved without making the Macro to run slow.

Comment: Are you able to ensure that entries in col A are sorted alphabetically?

Comment: Yes Col A is sorted...

Answer (score 1):

You may find your answer in the Consolidate tool that's built in under the Data tab. I know the standard use for that would add together the values, rather than presenting them as comma separated. Have a look in the function drop-down for options. Otherwise, you may be looking at a bit of old VBA to do the job for you. I think KuTools do something: http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1268-excel-combine-duplicate-rows-and-sum.html